# Header and footer not taking full width on an ipad despite width 100%

Tags: html, css

if you take a look at this link (link removed) **on an ipad**, you will notice that my header doesn't take the full width of the page, there's a full px gap on the right side. Same issue for the footer. I don't understand why because these elements have a 100% width in my CSS sheet and it looks perfect on my mac with safari and firefox. Any idea what is wrong? (didn't include the code here as there would have been too many lines since I don't know where the issue is) Thanks

[image]

Comment: CSS and html please or jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of your min-width in `html,body` Changing `min-width` to `1000px` will fix your issue.

**Change this**

```
html, body {
min-width: 980px;
```

**to this**

```
html, body {
min-width: 1000px;
```

Answer (score 0):

your style for `.wrapper` has a width of 1000px set on it. Removing `width:1000px` in line 452 of your style.css should do the trick